# Alternatives to BDB JE embedded database

Tags: database, jvm-languages, berkeley-db-je

I was using BDB JE since times it was developed by SleepyCat, than it was acquired by Oracle and the licensing policy is not clear now. So what are the alternatives to such key-value database with

- custom serializers of key and value objects
- ability to have secondary collections
- high throughput
- ability to store tens of millions records
- embedded into JVM-based app with no separate service/application
- low memory footprint

thanks!

Comment: Just out of interest, what isn't clear in the licensing policy?

Comment: it's free for opensource, but if you're going to ship your library as LGPL/BSD/etc - it doesn't work for commercial projects.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed sound weird.

Answer (score 4):

JDBM4 aka MapDB: https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb

"MapDB provides concurrent TreeMap and HashMap backed by disk storage or off-heap-memory. It is a fast, scalable and easy to use embedded Java database engine. It is tiny (160KB jar), yet packed with features such as transactions, space efficient serialization, instance cache and transparent compression/encryption. It also has outstanding performance rivaled only by native embedded db engines."

Comment: it's quite good, however I want to have secondary collections (collections, which value is the reference to a value in primary collection, but key is different). But thanks anyway!